# basic mysql code not working

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT(10000,1), 
    first_name varchar(20), 
    last_name varchar(20), 
    email_address varchar(50), 
    facebook_url varchar(50), 
    bio varchar(20)
);
```

the error given is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax : check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server for the right syntax to use **'PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT(10000,1), first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(2'** at line 1

Answer (score 6):

Your `user_id` column doesn't have a data type.

Also, I don't see anything in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) regarding your usage of `AUTO_INCREMENT`. If you remove the parameters you're attempting to pass in, it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f9c6

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues, you are missing the data type on my `user_id` field.  But if you want to set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to start at a specific value, then you need to use `ALTER TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
  user_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  first_name varchar(20), 
  last_name varchar(20), 
  email_address varchar(50), 
  facebook_url varchar(50), 
  bio varchar(20)
);
```

This will create your table but if you want to set to start value of the `Auto_Increment` from the [MySql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html):

> To change the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT counter to be used for new
>   rows, do this:
>
> ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;

Add the following line:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Test to be sure the values are working:

```
insert into users (first_name, last_name) values
('test1', 'test'),
('test2', 'test'),
('test3', 'test');
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46df6/1)

Or if you do not want to use `ALTER TABLE` you can consolidate into the `CREATE TABLE` statement with:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
  user_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  first_name varchar(20), 
  last_name varchar(20), 
  email_address varchar(50), 
  facebook_url varchar(50), 
  bio varchar(20)
)AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `AUTO_INCREMENT` on an `INTEGER` type column. So,

```
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT(10000,1),
```

Answer (score 0):

user_id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT(10000,1) has no data type defined.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  first_name varchar(20), 
  last_name varchar(20), 
  email_address varchar(50), 
  facebook_url varchar(50), 
  bio varchar(20)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    first_name varchar(20), 
    last_name varchar(20), 
    email_address varchar(50), 
    facebook_url varchar(50), 
    bio varchar(20)
);
```

You're missing column type (assuming INT) for user_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
CREATE TABLE users (user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000, PRIMARY KEY (user_id), first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(20), email_address varchar(50), facebook_url varchar(50), bio varchar(20));

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

CREATE TABLE `users` (`user_id` int(10) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT(10000,1), `first_name` varchar(20), `last_name` varchar(20), `email_address` varchar(50), `facebook_url` varchar(50), `bio` varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));

Comment: Using it, only the column names differ